# How to stop an animation in animator from playing without disabling it

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

What code to write for it to stop playing for example I want
animatorz.Play("Jump");
and I want to stop it how?
Also I already tried to make a empty state in anim but it just plays both of them.

For example I write anim.play i want it to stop so i do anim.stop which isnt possible and making an empty state it plays both of them

Comment: Try to get the object and set the animator enabled value to false. 

animatorz.gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().enabled = false;

Edit: Just read that you don't want to disable it, Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method 1: Somewhat complicated

Play the animation first:

animation.Play("Jump");

Pause the jump animation:

pausetime=animation["Jump"].time;

animation["Jump"].Stop();

Continue jumping animation:

animation["Jump"].time=pausetime;

animation.Play("Jump");

Method 2: Very simple

Play the animation first:

animation.Play("Jump");

Pause animation:

animation["Jump"].speed=0;

Continue the animation:

animation["Jump"].speed=1;

Comment: If you want to pause, the core statement is Animator.speed=0.0f;You can refer to this code, thank youprivate List<Object> test;
     private Animator animator;

     void Start(){
         animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
     }

     void Update(){
         if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W)){
             animator.speed = 0.0f
         }
         if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S)){
             animator.speed = 1.0f
         }
     }